# Is gwt slow or normal?

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

i want to ask about the speed of gwt-ext applications 
Are there any one tried Gwt-ext application and know that Is it slow or normal ?

can i handle images with gwt-ext as example i want to make the image black and white ?

thank you

saebnajim

Comment: gwt is as slow as you can code it =)
your question isnt very clear in what you are asking about.

Answer (score 9):

The compiled apps themselves do not run slow, but the GWT compiler is slower than a frozen snail with a lobotomy.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's important to remember some distinctions.

GWT-Ext is not representative of GWT's technology because it is simply a wrapper around a traditional JavaScript library (similar to YUI, which is where it branched from).

GXT is the same company's attempt at duplicating GWT-Ext using GWT the way it was intended; not wrapping hand-coded JavaScript, but letting GWT do most of the work. Unfornately, IMHO, they suck at it and have produced a load of garbage. It's very clunky and slow.

There's no reason plain GWT applications cannot be as fast or faster that GWT-Ext. I'll leave out the licensing discussion since it's not relevant to the question, but it's another thing to take into mind.

As for your add-on question regarding image manipulation... if that's possible, the only way I think you could do that is by using a Canvas element. GWT has a library of upcoming widgets (the 'incubator') which has a working Canvas widget.

[GWT Canvas Demo](http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/demo/com.google.gwt.demos.gwtcanvas.GWTCanvasDemo/GWTCanvasDemo.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using GWT-ext for my application and tested it on a slow computer in its browser. It is really fast and the animations are very smooth. The pure Java alternative GXT doesn't run so fast for me, altough i rather used this one because of better support.

Answer (score 0):

GWT-Ext is significantly slower than pure GWT application. Especially in form rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Developer console of GWT App looks much slower. but once the app is compiled & deployed in main server the application becomes more active and responds very quickly.. so decide about the speed of the application only after deploying. Just check its speed by deploying in jboss/apache server and check it. If you need to improve speed of application use code optimization tech and which will be more helpful in increasing response time.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my experience, not very complicated apps run quickly enough.
2. One thing I have noticed is that if you use Panels inside Panels inside Panels .... it takes a lot of time to load. Maby you should divide your Ext web app in several html pages and include a bit of Ext GWT in each of them.
3. something else you should consider is not building only GWT web pages. I like to use it only when i need it